# Google Maps Places not populating

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, wordpress

I'm trying to use Google Maps autocomplete on a search field, but all I need is a list of places in the dropdown based on what's been typed thus far - I don't actually need to update a map or anything.

I'm inserting the libraries through WP's enqueue function and it looks like this:

```
function typeright_enqueue() {
  wp_register_script( 'GMaps-Library', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' . get_option('maps_key') . '&sensor=false&libraries=places');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'GMaps-Library' );

  wp_register_script( 'GMaps-Call', plugins_url() . '/typeright-jobroller-plugin/js/gmaps-call.js');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'GMaps-Call' );    
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'typeright_enqueue');
```

From there I'm initialising the Google Places function through a call that looks like this:

```
function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('near');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

For some reason, when I look at the console, I can see activity from Google Maps, but there's no location dropdown appearing. What am I doing wrong?

There's a demo available at http://rockstar.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/ - the action is supposed to happen when using the "Location" input.

Hope someone can save my hairline...

Comment: The Google Maps library is being loaded twice.  From looking at the source of the link: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false&language=en&region=US&gl=US"></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCI1okJZQfdA2GMCjXN8OS95JAV0L5raeo&#038;sensor=false&#038;libraries=places&#038;ver=3.3.2'></script>` - the dev tools also show this warning `Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove the other library; That being said the second library only pulls the places module from my understandin, not the full one.